# viewForAnnotation detail disclosure changing current location as well as pins

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapkit

In my viewForAnnotation method I am adding a detail disclosure button to the right of the pin, however it changes the showsUserLocation to be a red pin, with a disclosure button to the right of the "Current Location" text.

How can I stop the current location symbol from being a pin? Without the method it is fine.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";

        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView =
        (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                              initWithAnnotation:annotation
                              reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

        // Create a UIButton object to add on the
        UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [annotationView setRightCalloutAccessoryView:rightButton];

    return annotationView;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add in the beginning of the method

```
 if (annotation == mapView.userLocation) {
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Hey! Man I'm kicking myself I didn't think of this! Still getting to grips with the language, but that seems so obvious! Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the docs, too:

> If the object in the annotation parameter is an instance of the MKUserLocation class, you can provide a custom view to denote the user’s location. To display the user’s location using the default system view, return nil.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKMapViewDelegate